# azure AAD user can't login vendor application base on azure

Tags: azure

We have Azure AD (AAD) in our company. Our mailbox will add .cn. For example, domain is abc@xxx.com, mailbox is abc@xxx.com.cn. When vendor grant for us the permission to use their apps base on Azure, we can't login or login with error. We need to login with AAD password but after that will pop out error. Vendor can just grant permission to access apps base on mailbox.

Request Id: 0772fbf2-4493-4ea5-8913-0b4928382100
Correlation Id: 273c0277-0a3e-4a70-8292-ee37c1e43f5d
Timestamp: 2020-10-13T07:54:24Z
Message: AADSTS90072: User account 'junexia@topformbras.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/5dd15f43-6a13-4730-b092-b76a786f8f55/' does not exist in tenant 'Dick's Sporting Goods, Inc.' and cannot access the application '53b3e540-259e-4de3-b8f9-17826ae79e0b'(FlexPLM) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using AAD B2B, for this to work the vendor needs to add you as a guest user in their tenant. You can see how guest users are created [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404).

Comment: There isn't really much more to add, I have added the docs for how to create guest users, but this is up to the vendor